# Last entry in a PHP database ID colum (primary key)

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the highest number in my ID column?

With MySQL I have the connection part done I just need to know how I can display that number using PHP. I got some of my code from a friend:

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("quollcraft.net", "quollcr1_forum", "pw");
    if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("quollcr1_hub", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recentplayers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 28");

    echo "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<center>";
        echo '<img class="avatar" src="http://cravatar.eu/avatar/' . $row ['name'] .         '/40.png" rel="tooltip" style="display: inline-block" title="' . $row ['name'] . '">';

        echo "</td>";
    echo "</table>";    




    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("quollcraft.net", "quollcr1_forum", "pw");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("quollcr1_hub", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<center>";

        echo "<p>' . $row ['id'] . 'hello</p>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</table>";    




    mysql_close($con);
    ?>`
```

Its supposed to show my latest players then the total players i have.

Comment: Even you already get tons of trivial answers (as the question might appear trivial), may I ask back why you need that MAX(ID) value? I assume you're looking for the current auto increment value, linking the dupe then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full row with the highest id not only the id, this would give you that

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you want the id as the only value you can do

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM table
```

If you want the total amount of rows in the table, to figure out how many players you have you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_players FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregate function `MAX()` to find the maximum value in a column:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as ID
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(YOUR COLUMN) FROM YOUR TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query should look like this

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

The solution with `MAX` may not be the best one when you have multiple records in database.

I don't know how you connect to your MySQL in PHP so it depends how you will display those max id in PHP

Comment: Can you provide an example where `MAX` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
SELECT id FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```